# grunt, grunt-shell - command inheritance

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

I need something like command inheritance like this:

```
shell:
    virtualenvActivate:
        command: [
            '. `command -v virtualenvwrapper.sh`'
            'workon <%= pkg.name %>'
        ].join '&&'
    pelican:
        command: [
            shell:virtualenvActivate # <-- THIS LINE
            'pelican src/content/ -o dist/ -s publishconf.py'
        ].join '&&'
```

Is it ever possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, CoffeeScript does not currently implements YAML's [anchor/reference](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2783797) features.

I don't know Grunt, but generally speaking, for now, you would probably have to declare the common data outside of your data structure:

```
_my_command = [
            '. `command -v virtualenvwrapper.sh`'
            'workon <%= pkg.name %>'
        ].join '&&'

shell:
    virtualenvActivate:
        command: _my_command
    pelican:
        command: [
            _my_command
            'pelican src/content/ -o dist/ -s publishconf.py'
        ].join '&&'
```

For more advanced use case, you probably can go to something like (ab)using an object constructor to achieve the desired result. Something *like* that maybe:

```
shell: new ->
    @virtualenvActivate =
        command: [
                    '. `command -v virtualenvwrapper.sh`'
                    'workon <%= pkg.name %>'
                ].join '&&'

    @pelican = 
        command: [
            console.log "A", this.virtualenvActivate
            @virtualenvActivate.command
            'pelican src/content/ -o dist/ -s publishconf.py'
        ].join '&&'
    @
```

That being said, I don't know if this would be the recommended way though.

Comment: I've tried the same way you proposed, but it didn't work. I just got error: `>> ReferenceError: _my_command is not defined`. It seems that even simple defined variable is unavailable there.